# Why am I unable to print the value output when the input is given to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, input, output

```
int value = 0;

int *pvalue = &value;

printf("input an integer:");

scanf("%d\n",*pvalue);

printf("you have entered %d\n",value);// this line is not printing in the output

return 0;
```

**my output is:**

```
input an integer:5
```

The other `printf` in the code is not printed in the output.

1. I tried to debug but it is giving a segmentation fault.
2. I want to give the value to the pointer and get the data

**please anyone tell me how to get the entered input as output in the printf**

Comment: scanf takes the address of the destination value. You should enter either scanf("%d", pvalue) or scanf("%d", &value), not *pvalue.

Comment: thank you for help, got the output

Comment: thank you for the answer, got the output

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `scanf()` should be the pointer itself, not a dereferenced pointer.

`*pvalue` is the same as `value`, which is `0`, so `scanf()` tries to write the output to `0` (`NULL`), an invalid location.